# RecyclerView and CardView on Fragment, No layout manager attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

i am trying display data via recyclerview from network, i found error on logcat its says: No layout manager attached; skipping layout.

This is my recyclerview code :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_utama, container, false);
       recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_utra);
        dataku = new ArrayList<>();
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4);
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getContext(), dataku);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy){
                if(gridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == dataku.size()-1){
                    Ambildatadariserver(dataku.get(dataku.size()-1).getId());
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

And this is my RecyclerAdapter :

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<DataJson> datajson;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<DataJson>datajson){
        this.context = context;
        this.datajson = datajson;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View Itemview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.daftart_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(Itemview);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvnama.setText(datajson.get(position).getNama());
        holder.tvemail.setText(datajson.get(position).getEmail());
        holder.tvtanggal.setText(datajson.get(position).getTanggal());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datajson.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView tvnama, tvemail, tvtanggal;
        public ViewHolder(View Itemview){
            super(Itemview);
            tvnama = (TextView) Itemview.findViewById(R.id.nama);
            tvemail = (TextView) Itemview.findViewById(R.id.email);
            tvtanggal = (TextView) Itemview.findViewById(R.id.tanggal);
        }
    }
}
```

My Fragment layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/utamas"
    tools:context="ptguwatirtasejahtera.utraposmobile.FragmentUtama"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_utra"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is MyCardView layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="Nama: "
        tools:text="Nama: "
        android:id="@+id/nama"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nama"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="Email: "
        tools:text="Email: "
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tanggal"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Tgl Lahir: "
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/nama"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the line:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Comment: that solve my issue, but recyclerview don't view anything.

Comment: You also need to put some items in the `dataku` list.